# Apple new certificate - where is the private key?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer

I generated a new IOS Distribution key in my Keychain app. It generated a CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest then I got the certificate from developer.apple.com.

Question is, where is the private key? I dont see it in my Keychain access, I only see private keys like "com.apple.kerberos.kdc" and such.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your certificate, in the keychain, there is an arrow next to it.

[image: Like htis]

If you want to export, you can right click on that key, and export it.

If the key does not appear here, it means you do not have the private key.

Comment: I dont see it there. I only see the certificate.

Comment: Then the CSR was not made on your laptop. If the CSR was made there, the private key would have been there.

Comment: I made the CSR request, I still have that. I also have a certificate.p12. But even after installing it I dont see the private key.

Comment: Can you put the screenshot in the question, or how your keychain looks?